# 2D array as contiguous block of memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc

I know this question was answered but it somehow doesn't work for me.
I dynamically allocate memory for array like this:

```
arr = (int**)(malloc(rows*sizeof(int*)));
arr[0] = (int*)(malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(int))); // <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK

printf("\nArray: \n");
while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) == 1) {   
    //arr[row] = (int*)(malloc(columns*sizeof(int))); <---THIS WORKS
    arr[row][col] = num;
    printf("%d ", arr[row][col]);
    if((++col == columns)){
        row++;          
        col = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It throws segmentation fault after 4th row, if matrix is 6x6.
Any advice? Thanks

EDIT:
See: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/ point number 4. If I do it like in point 3, it works. But I need it like in 4.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @juanchopanza If I want array to be allocated in one chunk of memory, I have to allocate it as in line with comment "<-- THIS DOESN'T WORK", problem is.....it doesn't work. If I allocate it in "while", every 1D array would be in different place of memory.

Comment: And what is the *question*?

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To allocate a *contiguous* memory, you'll have to use

```
arr  = malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);
arrayData = malloc(sizeof(int) * columns * rows);

for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     arr[i]  = arrayData + i * columns ;
```

To deallocate you'll need to have

```
free( arrData );
free( arr );
```

See [*here*](http://rextester.com/ELRW25177)

Comment: Search for contiguous memory allocation for 2D array on SO

Answer (score 7):

There exists no case where you should use fragmented malloc calls like you do. It is wide-spread but bad and incorrect practice. As you point out, it will not give you a true 2D array in adjacent memory, but rather a fragmented, slow mess.

How to do this properly:

In standard C, write

```
int (*arr)[rows][columns] = malloc (sizeof(*arr));
(*arr)[r][c] = something;
...

free(arr);
```

or if you prefer to use syntax which is easier-to-read (but perhaps harder to understand):

```
int (*arr)[columns] = malloc (sizeof(int[rows][columns]));
arr[r][c] = something;
...

free(arr);
```

In obsolete versions of C, you will have to write a "mangled array":

```
int* arr = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(*arr));
arr[r*c] = something;
...

free(arr);
```

Comment: Why you call the last one mangled array i do not know. Something else confused me. In the first case `sizeof(*arr)` equals 4 bytes (or the word size of the computer), does it equal `rows * columns * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @Nik-Lz It is called "mangled" because you can't use regular 2D array syntax when accessing it, but have to calculate the array index. `sizeof(*an_array_pointer)` does _not_ equal 4 bytes, but the size of the array. This is a difference between array pointers and regular pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for each `row`, not just the first `row`. Replace

```
arr[0] = (int*)(malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(int)));
```

with

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
```

The changes made here are:

1. All the rows will be allocated `columns * sizeof(int)` bytes of memory.
2. Casting the result of `malloc` is pointless in C. I've removed it.

---

You might need to add a check in the loop to prevent an overflow. Something like

```
if(row == rows)
{
    puts("Matrix full; Exiting loop...");
    break;
}
```

---

The fixed code would be

```
int i, row = 0, col = 0;
int rows = 6, columns = 6; /* For 6x6 matrix */

arr = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));

printf("\nArray: \n");
while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) == 1) {   
    arr[row][col] = num;
    printf("%d ", arr[row][col]);
    if(++col == columns){
        row++;          
        col = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(row == rows)
    {
        puts("Matrix full; Exiting loop...");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is already in my question, see line with comment "<-- THIS WORKS". But if I do it like this, every 1D array of 2D array would be in different place of memory. See: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/ point number 4.

Comment: You can't do it the way you want to

Comment: @iharob Well....ok, everyone seems to think the same, but can you give me a hint why this can't be done?

Comment: @Wlad Whoa. That fourth method is *really* confusing at first glance. Try `int i; for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) arr[i] = (arr[0] + i * columns);` just after `arr[0] = (int*)(malloc(rows*columns*sizeof(int)))` in your code.

Comment: However, this doesn't allocate a 2D array in adjacent memory cells.

Comment: @Lundin Wouldn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942134/2d-array-as-contiguous-block-of-memory/32942196?noredirect=1#comment53710353_32942196) do it?

Comment: @CoolGuy Forget about that "geeks for dinosaurs" link. 1999 is upon us, time to party, there's a new C standard. See my answer for better alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

For a 6x6 matrix, dynamic memory is overkill.  You should simply use:

```
int arr[rows][cols];
```

This is much simpler, cleaner, quicker, less error prone and generally all round safer — as long as you keep the matrix size small enough that it easily fits on the stack.  If you need a large matrix (say from 1 MiB upwards, but you'll need to tune your threshold to suit your systems), then dynamic memory is relevant.

You can make the single allocation to `arr[0]` work, but you have to do explicit assignments to each of `arr[1]` through `arr[5]`.  I did it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int rows = 6;
    int cols = 6;
    int **arr = (int**)(malloc(rows*sizeof(int*)));
    arr[0] = (int*)(malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int)));

    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i-1] + cols;

    printf("\nArray: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            arr[i][j] = (i+1) * (cols + 1 - j);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    free(arr[0]);
    free(arr);
    return(0);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Array: 
  7  6  5  4  3  2
 14 12 10  8  6  4
 21 18 15 12  9  6
 28 24 20 16 12  8
 35 30 25 20 15 10
 42 36 30 24 18 12
```

Running [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) gives a clean bill of health.

Comment: However, this doesn't allocate a 2D array in adjacent memory cells.

Comment: The data cells are a single contiguous array.

Comment: Oh right... only saw the pointer array allocation and dismissed it. Well anyway, this code is complete obscure, why would you ever want to write something like this? Just allocate an adjacent chunk of memory, no need for the array of pointers.

Comment: The OP wanted (or, at least, used) an array of pointers; I fixed up what he said doesn't work (and it didn't work because 83% of the pointers were uninitialized) so it does work.